# Prepend + or - to number

Tags: javascript

Is there any more efficient or native way to add a plus or minus symbol to a number?

Here's what I have:

```
function formatNumber(number) {
  if (number >= 0) {
    return "+" + number.toString();
  } else {
    if (number < 0) {
      return number.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems efficient enough. You don't need to use `toString()` when you already have a String (`"+"`).

Comment: You don't need  if inside else

Comment: `const formatNumber = n => n < 0 ? '' + n : '+' + n;`

Comment: Or slightly shorter: `const formatNumber = n => (n < 0 ? '' : '+') + n;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the if statement inside the else:

```
function formatNumber(number) {
  if (number >= 0) {
    return "+" + number;
  } else {
    return "" + number;
  }
}
```

Shorthand will be :

```
function formatNumber(number) {
    return (number>0?'+':'') + number;
}
```

Comment: `'-' + number` will duplicate the `-` for negative numbers - I’d go with `'' + number` instead

Comment: This looks simple, but perhaps is there any built-in JS method to do this?

Comment: @Juniorized as I know there's no built-in that add the plus sign to the positive numbers.

Comment: I was about to post an answer with the exact same code of your (edited) shorthand version, stating that returning the number would brake comparisons. +1 for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the else statement and also `toString` because JS will do it implicitly in case of string and number addition

```js
function formatNumber(number) {
  if (number >= 0) {
    return "+" + number;
  }
  return "" + number
}

console.log(formatNumber(1))
console.log(formatNumber(-1))
console.log(formatNumber(0))
```